# How to set up a custom template on Chartjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with the Line Chart from [ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) and with [the Angular extension](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) for that Plugin.

I am having difficulties trying to edit the tooltip so according to the Docs I need to create a custom template in order to achieve what I need

Here is what I have so far

[image]

as you see there is the tooltip but it is not displaying what I need, I need to display something like this:

> $AMOUNT (total)

so in this case it should be:

> $150 (1)

got it ?

See my code

```
      $scope.labels = Object.keys(data);
      $scope.seriesConv = ["amount"];
      $scope.dataConv = $scope.seriesConv.map(function(serie) {
        return $scope.labels.map(function(label) {
          $scope.trafficSource = Object.keys(data[label])[0];
          $scope.chartOptions = {
            tooltipTemplate: "<%= '$' + value %>",
          };
          return data[label][$scope.trafficSource].conversions.amount;
        });
      });
```

and html

```
   <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line"
           height="100" chart-options="chartOptions"
           chart-data="dataConv" chart-labels="labels">
   </canvas>
```

This is the data I am receiving

```
{
  "12-15-2015": {
    "55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4db0": {
      "conversions": {
        "total": 0,
        "amount": 0
      },
      "clicks": {
        "total": 8,
        "real": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "12-16-2015": {
    "55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4db0": {
      "conversions": {
        "total": 0,
        "amount": 0
      },
      "clicks": {
        "total": 18,
        "real": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "12-17-2015": {
    "55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4db0": {
      "conversions": {
        "total": 1,
        "amount": 22
      },
      "clicks": {
        "total": 12,
        "real": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "12-18-2015": {
    "55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4db0": {
      "conversions": {
        "total": 0,
        "amount": 0
      },
      "clicks": {
        "total": 6,
        "real": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "12-19-2015": {
    "55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4db0": {
      "conversions": {
        "total": 0,
        "amount": 0
      },
      "clicks": {
        "total": 12,
        "real": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "12-20-2015": {
    "55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4db0": {
      "conversions": {
        "total": 0,
        "amount": 0
      },
      "clicks": {
        "total": 10,
        "real": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "12-21-2015": {
    "55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4db0": {
      "conversions": {
        "total": 1,
        "amount": 22
      },
      "clicks": {
        "total": 1,
        "real": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "12-22-2015": {
    "55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4db0": {
      "conversions": {
        "total": 1,
        "amount": 150
      },
      "clicks": {
        "total": 1,
        "real": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "12-26-2015": {
    "55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4db0": {
      "conversions": {
        "total": 0,
        "amount": 0
      },
      "clicks": {
        "total": 4,
        "real": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "12-28-2015": {
    "55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4db0": {
      "conversions": {
        "total": 0,
        "amount": 0
      },
      "clicks": {
        "total": 1,
        "real": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "12-29-2015": {
    "55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4db0": {
      "conversions": {
        "total": 0,
        "amount": 0
      },
      "clicks": {
        "total": 1,
        "real": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "01-03-2016": {
    "55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4db0": {
      "conversions": {
        "total": 0,
        "amount": 0
      },
      "clicks": {
        "total": 2,
        "real": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "01-04-2016": {
    "55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4db0": {
      "conversions": {
        "total": 0,
        "amount": 0
      },
      "clicks": {
        "total": 3,
        "real": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "01-05-2016": {
    "55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4db0": {
      "conversions": {
        "total": 0,
        "amount": 0
      },
      "clicks": {
        "total": 6,
        "real": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "01-06-2016": {
    "55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4db0": {
      "conversions": {
        "total": 0,
        "amount": 0
      },
      "clicks": {
        "total": 6,
        "real": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "01-10-2016": {
    "55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4db0": {
      "conversions": {
        "total": 0,
        "amount": 0
      },
      "clicks": {
        "total": 1,
        "real": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "01-11-2016": {
    "55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4db0": {
      "conversions": {
        "total": 0,
        "amount": 0
      },
      "clicks": {
        "total": 2,
        "real": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "01-14-2016": {
    "55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4db0": {
      "conversions": {
        "total": 0,
        "amount": 0
      },
      "clicks": {
        "total": 22,
        "real": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

for now I am just playing with the `"conversions : {}` part of the Object, which contains `total` and `amount`

so according to the Docs of those links, what do you think I should do in order to achieve what I want?

Comment: "<%= '$' + total + '(' + amount + ')' %>"

Comment: @ymz how do I know the info I have available to put between this `<%= %>` ???

Comment: I did that `"<%= '$' + total + '(' + amount + ')' %>"` and got undefined